# Smarty 3 multilanguage plugin

Tags: mysql, database, plugins, smarty, multilingual

I've used Smarty to create a multilanguage site and I would to connect a small admin panel to handle texts in different languages.

I found this Smarty function http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyMultilanguageSupport that is very nice. I've modify this function to make it work on Smarty 3.

There is a problem: I would use the db and not the LNG file. How can I modify the function for take the data from db?

someone has other Smarty 3 or Php plugin for multilanguage from db?

Comment: I want to do the same thing have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a new _loadTranslationTable function within the ngLanguage class: anything that casts the result of your database query into an array and stores it into $this->__translationTable[$yourlanguage] should do.